# PHP return Logged In User

Tags: php, joomla, intercom

I run a Joomla based site and I am trying to get intercom to pull the logged-in user data via php. Does anyone know what the correct formula is for these lines (or where I can find it?):

```
<?php echo $current_user->name ?>
<?php echo $current_user->email ?>
```

Second question: what would happen is there was no logged-in user?

FYI: I'm unfortunately not php fluent!

Full code:

```
<script>
  window.intercomSettings = {
    app_id: "*****",
    name: "<?php echo $current_user->name ?>", // Full name
    email: "<?php echo $current_user->email ?>", // Email address
    created_at: <?php echo strtotime($current_user->created_at) ?> // Signup date as a Unix timestamp
  };
</script>
<script>(function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments)};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args)};w.Intercom=i;function l(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='https://widget.intercom.io/widget/unvfagbb';var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);}if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})()</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the user object: (put this line before the <script> tag)

```
$current_user = JFactory::getUser();
```

see also: https://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly pull the data from Joomla to Intercom, you need to call the joomla framework and access the user properties. First you need to use this code to get connected to Joomla

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define('JPATH_BASE', "C:\Vertrigo\www\joomla" );// Your Joomla Installation folder
//Next call the mandatory framework files
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
//Initialise the mainframe
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
//get user details
$user = JFactory::getUser();
//To get current logged in user
$current_user->name = $user->username;
$current_user->email =$user->email;
```

If you dont have any logged in user you get userid = 0 or guest so likewise you can change your code with if else statement. `if($user->id ==0)` etc